# fancy box callback function .load jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox

```
$("#btnOK").click(function(){
    parent.$("#res"+(d)).load("Customise.php #uni", "PID="+$("#P option:selected").val());
    parent.$.fancybox.close(function(){
    $("#res"+(d-1)+" a#p").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            'width':400,
            'height':300,
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0.5,
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
    });
});
```

after i click the button. i use a callback function to reintialise a#p it can't work?
any solution?

```
        <div class="cell">
    <label id="pID">PID</label> <br /> <input type="text" id="txtPID" size="3" value="<? if(is_numeric($pID)) print("$pID"); ?>"/>   
    <a href="SelectP.html" id="p"><img src="Images/P.png" name="SelectP_button" id="SelectP_button" /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess we are missing some information here. What do you want to achieve? ... is this code inside an iframe? where is the selector `"#res"+(d-1)+"a#p"` ... inside the iframe or the parent page? can you show your html too? ...  help yourself to get help.

Comment: then I guess you should be using the `onClosed` call back in the parent page to re-initialize the selector `"#res"+(d-1)+"a#p"` and not from the child page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#btnOK").click(function(){
    parent.$("#res"+(d)).load("Customise.php #uni", "PID="+$("#P option:selected").val());
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
});


$("#res"+(d-1)+" a#p").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'width':400,
        'height':300,
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.5,
        'onClosed: function(){
         $("#res"+(d-1)+" a#p").fancybox({
                   'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                   'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300,
                    'overlayOpacity'    : 0.5,
                    'type'              : 'iframe'
                     });
         },
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Comment: but there is an issue with this code. if i run it 2 time it be invalid. because the inner fancybox does not have onclosed let say if i have an onclosed on the inner fancybox i will be doing unlimited times.

Comment: I didn't check your code, I just meant that using `onClosed` callback is the right way to go. Still I think we are missing more information here because you are not clear what html and js is in the parent page and what is in the child page. For instance, where is the html for the selector `#btnOK`? ... you keep us guessing.

Comment: j.js, A.html B.html. A.html will load b.html into a fancy box. b.html will refresh A.html after B has complete it function and close.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you want to select $("#res"+(d-1)+"a#p") ?

Im assuming that d is a number and you will therefore generate:

```
#res3a#p
```

in your selector, which is invalid, youre probably trying to do this

```
$("#res"+(d-1)+" a#p")
```

Comment: it is valid. i have other part using the same code and it work perfectly fine. what is not working is the reattach of the code. the spacing is not the issue.